# eclipse plugin: How to programmatically select text in editor?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I want to programmatically jump to a position in the text editor and highlight code.

Comment: The Eclipse API is a maze. I could find plenty of google hits on how to "get" the current selection, but not to "set" the selection.

Comment: found this via googleling (not directly on-topic) ... if you want to mark a block of code semi-automatically (e.g. some `sql` block/query inside some `plsql` function) for execution (e.g. in `SQL File Editor`) you could use the pretty generic *Nodeclipse Editor Plugin* with `ALT+Z` on the currrently hovered/marked block: https://github.com/Nodeclipse/EditBox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't able to get [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775795/105137) to work in Eclipse 3.7. The compiler gave this error:

```
The method getSourceViewer() from the type AbstractTextEditor is not visible.
```

However, I was able to get it to work with the `selectAndReveal()` method:

```
IFile myfile = ...
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) IDE.openEditor(page, myfile);
editor.selectAndReveal(offset, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a handle on the current editor, then you can do:

```
editor.getSourceViewer().setSelectedRange(offset, length);
```

If you don't have a handle on the current editor, then you need to do some work to get there (assuming a text editor):

```
TextEditor editor = (TextEditor) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
    .getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
```

Although this will work, I've simplified a few things.

1. You need to make sure that the active editor really is a `TextEditor`, so you are going to want to do an instanceof test
2. Sometimes various parts of the long phrase above can be null (eg- during startup or shutdown).  I tend to just wrap the expression in a try-catch(NPE) block and assume that if an NPE is thrown, then the editor is not available.