# How to open a new eclipse editor with a specific cursor offset position

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, editor

I would like to do the above programmatically.
I looked on [How to get cursor position in an eclipse TextEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827797/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-an-eclipse-texteditor) and [Eclipse-plugin how to get current text editor corsor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619623/eclipse-plugin-how-to-get-current-text-editor-corsor-position) so i kind of know how get the cursor offset from the **current** open editor. However, I'm trying to set the cursor offset in a new editor which is opened programmatically by me.

The way I'm currently open my new editor is as follows:

```
IWorkbenchWindow win = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
    if (page != null) {
        IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
        if (editor != null) {
            IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
            if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput) {
                String fileLocation = ((IFileEditorInput) input).getFile().getLocation().toOSString();
                String newFileLocartion = generateNewFileLocation(fileLocation);
                File file = new File(newFileLocartion);
                IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(file.toURI());
                try {
                    IDE.openEditorOnFileStore(page, fileStore);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    // TODO error handling
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to open set the new editor to open in a specific offset (assuming i already knows the offset in advance)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I used the following, which is more simple than the previous answer. Assuming you have `int offset`, `IWorkbenchPage page` and `IFile file` (and it seems that they all exist in the OP's question):

```
ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) IDE.openEditor(page, file);
editor.selectAndReveal(offset, 0);
```

I found out how to do this from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775630/eclipse-plugin-how-to-programmatically-select-text-in-editor/8776449#8776449) (but by setting the second parameter of *selectAndReveal* to zero, no text is highlighted)

Answer (score 3):

It use this snippet to navigate to specified line in a file.

```
public static void navigateToLine(IFile file, Integer line)
{
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);
    IMarker marker = null;
    try {
        marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.TEXT);
        marker.setAttributes(map);
        try {
            IDE.openEditor(getActivePage(), marker);
        } catch ( PartInitException e ) {
            //complain
        }
    } catch ( CoreException e1 ) {
        //complain
    } finally {
        try {
            if (marker != null)
                marker.delete();
        } catch ( CoreException e ) {
            //whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Probably not exactly what you need, but could be useful. (//complain replaces error handling code that was specific to product where this is used )